# Is there easy way to make json data in mysql?

Tags: sql, json, mariadb

I have a logging table which log changed fields in json format.
Right now, we pulling the whole data per version and diff and save it in application. But it pull lots of data so it could raise OOM so I want to do it on db side.

I could get changed records by self join, but I have no idea to make changed data in json.

Is there way to generate json string ?

Below is schema.

```
create table A { id int not null primary key auto_increment, 
             code int not null, 
             version int not null, 
             name varcher(10) not null,
             content varcahr(10) not null ) ;

create table logging ( id int not null primary key auto_increment, 
                   version int not null,
                   code int not null,
                   changed varcher(1024) );

INSERT INTO logging ( version, code , changed ) 
SELECT A2.version, A2.code, ?                  <- I don't know how create json 
FROM A A1 inner join A A2 ON A1.code = A2.code
WHERE A1.version = 1 AND A2.version = 2 
  AND ( A1.name != A2.name OR A1.content != A2.content )
```

I want to make a json like below
    { "name":"UPDATED"} if only name is changed
    { "name":"UPDATED", "content": "UPDATED_CONTENT"} if name & content is changed.

I'm using MariaDB 10.0.22

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I completely understand the desired output (as there is no sample data and sample output on post).

Also, I don't think there's a MySQL command to translate data to JSON. 
You can do it on the application side which may be easier, or you can build it in the query with string concatenation (generally this is not best practice! May be OK if your JSON syntax is pretty simple and short).

Storing JSON strings in a database is also not best practice - why is table `logging` needed if you have table `A`?

```
INSERT INTO logging ( VERSION, CODE , CHANGED ) 
SELECT A2.version, A2.code, 
IF(A1.content = A2.content,
    -- no content change
    CONCAT("{\"name\":\"", A2.name, "\"}"),
    -- content was also changed
    CONCAT("{\"name\":\"", A2.name, "\", \"content\": \"", A2.content, "\"}")) AS json_description                    
FROM A A1 INNER JOIN A A2 ON A1.code = A2.code
WHERE A1.version = 1 AND A2.version = 2 
  AND (A1.name != A2.name OR A1.content != A2.content)
```

Comment: Agree that best practice would be to assemble JSON on the application side rather than on the database side.